# Newbie to linking SQL tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL, so forgive me if I am understanding this incorrectly.

I have one table named Employees, where I have columns for:

```
EmployeeID - This is Int Identity (1,1)
FirstName
LastName
```

I have a second table named Calendar, with the calendar information populated for the next 50 years. Columns are:

```
FullDate
Year
Month
Week
DayofWeek
DayofMonth
DayofYear
TypeofDay - (Weekday, Weekend, Bank holiday etc)
```

Now for where I'm a little confused - I think I need a third table (Table3) that links the two above tables, so I have a table with something like:

```
TableId
FullDate - linked from calendar table
EmployeeID - linked from employee table
FirstName - linked from employee table
LastName - linked from employee table
Shift1Text
Shift2Text
```

If my understanding is correct, I can then use a command like:

```sql
select * from Table3 where FullDate = **Chosen Date / DateRange**
```

so I would end up with an output along the lines of:

```
Table ID | FullDate   | EmployeeID | FirstName | LastName | Shift1Text | Shift2Text 
---------+------------+------------+-----------+----------+------------+------------
1        | 22/06/2015 | 1          | Joe       | Blogs    | SomeText   | SomeText   
2        | 22/06/2015 | 2          | Fred      | Smith    | SomeText   | SomeText   
3        | 22/06/2015 | 3          | Bob       | Jones    | SomeText   | SomeText   
4        | 23/06/2015 | 1          | Joe       | Blogs    | SomeText   | SomeText   
5        | 23/06/2015 | 2          | Fred      | Smith    | SomeText   | SomeText
```

and so on...

The problem is, I have no idea how to go about linking the tables in this way, or automatically populating the rows of the third table with the date and employee info from the first 2 tables.

Comment: The use of `identity` suggests SQL Server, so I'm removing the "mysql" tag.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  This site works best when you have more than a basic understanding of the programming language you are using AND a specific question to ask.  You may get more mileage out of a SQL or database tutorial (such as http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_intro.asp) before asking a question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to add ID in you Calender table so your schema should be something like this[image]

*Note :* in EmployeeDate table you dont need to add FirstName or LastName because you have EmployeeID which references to Employee table where you can easy get those fields.

And your query will be like this.

```
Select * from Employee as E
  Join EmployeeDate as ED 
    on E.EmployeeID = ED.EmployeeID
  Join DateTable D 
    on D.Dateid = ED.Dateid
Where D.fulldate = <your full Date>
```

Thank

Comment: This is certainly along the lines that I was thinking, but is there anyway to automatically populate the EmployeeDate table with the DateID from the date table and EmployeeID from the employee table, so all I need to change is the shift text for a particular DateID and employeeID combination

Comment: Its complicated a bit, first you have to add DateID in your Calender table than you can use Rank() or Row_Number method to get right ID for your EmployeeDate table

Answer (score 0):

You need to avoid duplicating data between tables, and instead do a join in your query. The link exists with the employee ID in the Calender table, so you don't need the third table. Roughly speaking, your query would look something like this:

```
select c.fulldate, e.employeeid, e.firstname, e.lastname (other columns....)
from employees e
join calendar c on c.employeeid = e.employeeid
```

Otherwise, look into using a view (if my-sql can use them?)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I don't really understand what your table Calendar does. But If you link the two tables like tht, this means that one employee has one calendar. In the case of one employee has multiple calendar you have to remove the primary key from Calendar. Primary key means unique. For employee it means that employees cannot share the same ID.

I don't understand what is the link between your employees and your Calendar